# Joomla site won't display in IE after migration

Tags: php, mysql, windows, joomla, migration

Here is my joomla site: http://emmarosecharter.com/

I recently moved the site to a new server - moved all the files with ftp and set up the database with mysql workbench.

The site had previously worked perfect in all browsers but now only displays fine in Chrome, Firefox, on mobile devices. But won't display at all on IE.

I couldn't find any answers as to whats going on. Is anyone familiar with this issue or can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this still an issue? It is working on IE!

Comment: fixed it. was an issue with the iss server